# Scala ObjectInputStream make program fail silent

Tags: sockets, scala

I have a program that creates an actor and then reads from the default input.
If i write the folowing on a trait that make the basic actor it works on the "Act" method:

```
 trait SocketActor extends Actor{


protected def sock:Socket


protected val in:BufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.sock.getInputStream()))
protected val out:PrintWriter= new PrintWriter(this.sock.getOutputStream(), true)

def act(){
     println("This get to be executed")
 }
```

If i write the following it doesn't execute the act method

```
 trait SocketActor extends Actor{


protected def sock:Socket


protected val in:ObjectInputStream=new ObjectInputStream(this.sock.getInputStream())
protected val out:ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream (this.sock.getOutputStream())
def act(){
     println("This  doesn't get to be executed")
 }
```

The creation of the actor can be resumed as follow:

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
import scala.io._
import game.io._
class PlayerActor(protected val sock:Socket) extends {

} with SocketActor
object TabuClient{
    def main(args:Array[String]){
    try{
        println("Always exected on both cases")
        val port=1337
        val s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), port)

        val a=new PlayerActor(s)
        a.start()

        for (line <- io.Source.stdin.getLines){
            a.sendMessage(line)
        }
        s.close()
    }
    catch{
        case e:Throwable=>{
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

Both ways compile, but the second basically fails after the actor start without throwing exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following to the object input stream solved it, funny enough it didn't need the lazy if it's just an inputStream

```
trait SocketActor extends Actor{


protected def sock:Socket


protected lazy val in:ObjectInputStream=new ObjectInputStream(this.sock.getInputStream())
protected lazy val out:ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream (this.sock.getOutputStream())
def act(){
     println("This  doesn't get to be executed")
 }
```